# How do I tell a coworker about her stinky body odor?

Tags: colleagues, unprofessional-behavior, offices

One of my coworkers wears sleeveless shirts very often and it is obvious she is not wearing deodorant. Often her armpits emit a onion odor. How can I tell her it smells bad? Should I tell her? Or should I simply anonymously gift her deodorant?
It is particularly offensive, given that she obnoxiously complains about anything that others say or do that bothers her, but she does not take criticism well at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in the same situation, but I was the one giving the odor. My Co-worker (who sit's next to me) on a smoke break, told me I was giving off a bit of a smell ( which I personally didn't realise, only after he said it), as of then I'm starting to take showers early morning and late night to combat my problem. - Long story short, say to your co-worker, politely that they are giving off a little bit of an odor (of course in a break time). Something along the lines of "Hey, just so you know you're giving off a little bit of an odor, maybe shower in the mornings not late at nights".

Comment: You could start off trying to hint - sniff your own armpit and ask 'Is that me?' out loud